# Как передать jvm options в сервлет на websphere

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm, websphere

Есть следующий конфиг

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@ToString
@Configuration
@PropertySource( value = {
        "classpath:some-config.properties",
        "file:${config.global}/some-config.properties"
}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true )
public class SomeConfig {
    ... 
}
```

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность переопределять настройки "извне", я могу создать файл по пути `${config.global}/some-config.properties`, однако, это требует передачи дополнительного jvm аргумента `-Dconfig.global=somePath` на стадии деплоя сервлета в webspere. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу передать этот параметр в вебсферу?

Answer (score 0):

#### Application Server

- В административной консоли выбираете "*Серверы*"(`Servers`)
- Разворачиваете выпадающий список "*Тип сервера*" (`Server Type`) и выбираете "*WebSphere*"
- Нажимаете на имя вашего сервера
- Разворачиваете выпадающий список "*Java и управление процессами*" ( `Java and Process Management` ) и выбираете "*Определение процесса*" (`Process Definition`).
- Под разделом дополнительных свойств ( `Additional Properties` ) нажимаете на "*Java Virtual Machine*".
- Прокручиваете до поля `*Generic JVM arguments*`
- Вводите аргументы

Источник: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-generic-jvm-arguments-websphere-application-server